# Is there a python package out there that can identify natural language time expressions?

Tags: python, datetime, nlp, package, stanford-nlp

I have been looking for a package that can identify time expressions from simple text messages and then convert them into datetime. I have seen one called ctparse, however, it can't understand expressions like: next weekend, this week, etc.

Is there a package out there that is good for this sort of thing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Next weekend" and "this week" are going to be difficult as either of those is a time period, not a date, but for more concrete cases you can try `dateutil.parser`:

```
import dateutil.parser as dps

In [4]: a = 'next Monday'

In [5]: b = dps.parse(a, fuzzy=True)

In [6]: b
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 21, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm needing something with those time periods.

Comment: @noahn, fair enough but what datetime you want to get if you have "next weekend" in the text? Once again, it's not a datetime, it can't be expressed with python datetime object.

Comment: I guess I would want for it to give Saturday at 12:01

Comment: Actually, that gave me a great idea I made a dictionary to change words like week to Monday or weekend to Saturday in the input string